# not enough disk space in "/tmp" temporary directory. 100 MB is required for startup

Tags: yocto, intel-mkl, openembedded

I am installing Intel MKL into yocto.

Here is my part of bb:

```
S = "${WORKDIR}/l_mkl_2020.0.166/"

do_install () {
   install -d -m 755 ${D}/opt/intel
   install -d -m 755 ${D}/tmp
   ./install.sh -t ${D}/tmp
}
```

when bitbake it, it will show:

```
not enough disk space in "/tmp" temporary directory. 100 MB is required for startup.
```

I saw a same issue:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/733523

No solution yet.

Comment: Maybe patch install.sh to remove space check?

Comment: It seems Intel provides MKL Yocto support through `meta-intel-iss` [here](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/set-up-analysis-target/embedded-linux-targets/configure-yocto-project-with-iss-integration-layer.html?wapkw=meta-intel-iss), maybe you have it?

Comment: How about MPI, do intel also support it in yocto?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not using ISS myself